# New Edition of TeXBook

Tags: tex-core, books, learning, knuth

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62903/transition-from-latex-to-plain-tex) I asked a question about moving from LaTeX to plain TeX and one of the recommendations was to look Knuth's TeXBook.

I was looking into this when I came across [this](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html#all-electronic) update on Knuth's website, money quote:

> The original editions of these books were produced with the technology
>   of the 1980s: I supplied “camera-ready copy” (produced with TeX and
>   METAFONT) and the publishers used a special camera to photograph that
>   copy and to make negative images, from which plates could be produced
>   for use on offset printing presses. Many illustrations were prepared
>   first as photostats and “stripped in” by hand, using an interesting
>   process called “waxing.” Shaded parts of the illustrations were
>   photographically “screened,” etc.
>
> Dozens of subsequent printings, including those of the Millennium
>   Edition, were made from the original camera negatives, with
>   replacement pages inserted when necessary but with the original
>   illustrations retained.
>
> But finally at the end of 2011, when it became necessary to reprint
>   these books again with all of the latest corrections that have been
>   suggested by the world's best nitpickers, the publishers discovered
>   that the original films had been lost! That was bad news for me,
>   because it meant that I had to put The Art of Computer Programming on
>   the back burner for a month while working hard to reconstruct more
>   than 2600 pages of highly technical material, including the remaking
>   and placing of more than 1000 illustrations. But it was good news for
>   everybody else, because now the latest printings are produced entirely
>   with technology that can be expected to last for many generations, and
>   the books themselves are significantly better in hundreds of small
>   ways. I went through every page very carefully and introduced many
>   refinements, which have made me extremely happy with the result. I'm
>   now able to replace my personal desk copies, in which hundreds of
>   handwritten notes had been scrawled since the Millennium edition came
>   out, by fresh versions that are essentially perfect (as far as I
>   know). This is especially true of Volume B, because important updates
>   to the TeX software that were made in 2002 and 2007 have never before
>   been available in print.
>
> These new and updated printings of Volumes A, B, and C became
>   available in April, 2012, including a new paperback version (12th
>   printing) of The METAFONTbook. Hardcoverwise, the new Volume A is the
>   19th printing; the new Volume B is the 9th; and the new Volume C is
>   the 8th. New printings of Volumes D and E are also “in press,” but not
>   yet released.

So my question is whether the [copy sold on Amazon.ca](http://www.amazon.ca/Computers-Typesetting-Donald-E-Knuth/dp/0201134470/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1342692852&sr=8-3) is in fact the new "spiffy" editions Knuth is talking about, or are they trying to run down their inventory of the older editions first.

Comment: The issue is interesting but the question about Amazon is not relevant to this site.

Comment: I agree. Maybe you should just send them an email.

Comment: I think you get the reprint only in the " Millennium Boxed Set".

Comment: Related: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100060/the-texbook-spiral-or-hard-cover-binding (from 2013) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222321/where-to-find-the-spiffy-new-printings-of-knuths-computers-typesetting-book (from 2015), both later than this question (but neither of them closed like this one).