# The TeXbook: Spiral or hard-cover binding?

Tags: best-practices, books, knuth

I would like to purchase Donald Knuth's TeXbook, and I have noticed that there are two versions available. One is a spiral-bound edition, usually sold by itself. The other is a hard-cover edition, available both by itself or as part of a boxed set of five volumes (Knuth's Computers and Typesetting series). The price difference between the two is minimal, so I'm unsure which to purchase.

If anyone here owns one or both editions, perhaps they could answer at least some of the questions below, to help me make up my mind.

1. Can the hard-cover edition stay open when placed on a surface (like many mathematics textbooks), or does it have to be propped open by the reader (like many hard-cover novels, which usually have very tight bindings)?
2. What is the cover of the spiral-bound edition like? Does it stand up well to repeated handling?
3. I have read reviews of the spiral-bound edition stating that the pages often fall out from the end of the book. Is this a serious problem?
4. Are there any other considerations to bear in mind when making a choice between these two editions?

Comment: I have the spiral and the hard cover.  I much prefer the hard cover.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: I would also argue for the hardcover; in general spiral bound books are not of very good quality, and will be much easier to rip, lose pages from, etc. Years of textbook buying taught me to stay away from cheaper spiral bound editions at all costs (and if they're the same price, all the more reason to get the nicer one).

Comment: when i bought my first copy, _long_ ago, the spiral bound was noticeably cheaper.  so i got that; only more recently did i buy the hardback.  i keep the spiral bound at work; it's beginning to look a bit sloppy, but it's not lost any pages yet.  i use the hardback rather less regularly, since i've a garden, a wife and a cat to look after at home...

Comment: FWIW, my 20yo blue spiral-bound texbook still has all its pages, but they're pretty grubby, and the bookmarking back cover is a bit tatty.  The wire spiral is in OK shape.  It will see me out.  If there was price-parity back then, I would have bought the hard cover.

Comment: In addition to hard copy, free `tex` books in pdf can be accessed from terminal/commandwindow with `texdoc tex`, `texdoc texbytopic` and `texdoc impatient`

Comment: @texenthusiast Not in MiKTeX. So it would be better to point to http://mirror.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/ and http://mirror.ctan.org/info/impatient/ (or to http://mirror.ctan.org/info/texbytopic.zip and http://mirror.ctan.org/info/impatient.zip) – but what is supposed to be opened with `texdoc tex`?

Comment: at the bottom of [don knuth's tex page](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/abcde.html) there is a section "spiffy new printings".  late in 2011, knuth updated the texbook sources to incorporate all corrections and suggestions, but only the hardcover has the updated text.  even more problematic is the fact that it's identified as a *printing*, not an *edition*, so it is not possible to tell from most distributors which you would get.  i've been led to believe that if you are a tug member ordering via the tug link, (continued ...)

Comment: (... continued) and you explicitly request the 19th printing, but an older one is delivered, you can write to the publisher, state the circumstances of your case, and the problem will be resolved.  (i don't have a guarantee in writing, but the claim was made in good faith.  don't expect this service from amazon.)

Comment: re spiral-bound, i have a copy of the first edition, with many handwritten notes; the back cover and last half-dozen pages are held on with a large paper clip -- but i keep it on the shelf next to my more usual working copy, also spiral bound (21st printing, 1992) which is basically devoid of notes.  one of these days i'll get around to ordering a copy of the 2011 updated printing, hardbound only.  but since ams mostly uses latex these days, i have more immediate need of latex manuals, to quote to misguided authors.

Comment: @Speravir 'texdoc tex' launches a Lua TeX Reference pdf on my Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: @texenthusiast Oddly enough, it doesn't in my distribution. The other strange thing is that the other parameters you mentioned, such as 'texbytopic', result in a "no documentation found" message. Maybe I'm missing some packages? 

Either way, both your comment and that of Speravir were useful, as I was able to find all the docs mentioned online.

Comment: `texdoc tex` in MiKTeX launches the "manpage" of the `tex` executable formatted as HTML in the default browser.

Comment: in similar conditions _choose best version_, in this case hard cover

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Disclaimer! This answer contains pictures that may be shocking to book lovers. 
Reader discretion is advised.**

I picked up a spiral-bound copy from the university library. Because it must have been handled by quite a lot of (probably careless) hands over the years, it is perhaps an extreme case, but it give some good indication as to whether the book (not its immortal contents!) stands the test of time. See below, from the 4th picture onwards.

The hardcover copy I have, on the other hand, is brand new.
EDIT: Relevant information about that version (the 19th printing) can be found on the third picture below.

So, to answer your questions:

1. The [hardcover version](http://www.informit.com/store/computers-typesetting-volume-a-the-texbook-9780201134476) has a pleasantly loose binding. I haven't used my copy yet and it already stays open when placed on a flat surface without any effort. See the second picture below.
2. The spiral-bound copy I'm looking at is nice to handle but is in bad shape: the frontcover is ok but the backcover is almost torn apart from the spiral-binding coil and the latter has its guts showing at the bottom.
3. As far as I know, it's not missing any pages, but the last few pages do tend to come apart because of the poor state of the spiral-binding coil.
4. See [Barbara Beeton's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104130/21891). I might update my answer later if I find glaring differences between the spiral-bound and hardcover versions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shocking! The title is covered with a barcode, what a shame!

Comment: @topskip That was not my doing; and you should have stayed away after reading my disclaimer :)

Comment: oh, this isn't so extreme.  my very early (possibly first) printing is in even worse shape, and i'm the only one who has ever used it.  (and i'm pretty careful with books.)  the spiral binding *does* lie flat, but unless the holes are reinforced, they take a real beating with heavy use.  as noted in an earlier comment, the back cover and several pages have actually separated, and are held on with a large peper clip.  but since that copy is annotated, it hasn't been put out to pasture yet.

Comment: @Jubobs -- turn to the back of the title page of the hardcover version.  at the bottom left, the first number in that line should be the printing.  if that is "19", you have the fully updated version.  now, find knuth's cumulative errata list.  in a tex live distribution, it's in `doc/generic/knuth/errata/errata.pdf`.  look for the most recent collection; should be easy to identify.  every item is dated and the page number specified.  you should be able to find things not in the spiral-bound version; compare the hardcover, and report, please.

Comment: +1 Very funny (even if not intended) Disclaimer!

Answer (score 18):

at the bottom of don knuth's tex page there is a section "spiffy new printings". late in 2011, knuth updated the texbook sources to incorporate all corrections and suggestions, but only the hardcover has the updated text. even more problematic is the fact that it's identified as a printing, not an edition, so it is not possible to tell from most distributors which you would get.

i've been led to believe that if you are a tug member ordering via the tug link, and you explicitly request the 19th printing, but an older one is delivered, you can write to the publisher, state the circumstances of your case, and the problem will be resolved. (i don't have a guarantee in writing, but the claim was made in good faith. don't expect this service from amazon.)

[the link to the pearson publishing group at the tug web site](http://tug.org/books/#pearsonaffil) now indicates that one does not have to be a tug member to take advantage of a 30% discount on addison-wesley books about tex and friends.  the procedure for ordering is described on the linked web page.

(feedback on whether the copy delivered really is the updated 19th printing would be welcome.  in fact, @Jubobs has reported his success in a comment to *his* answer.)

if someone has two copies of the book with possibly different contents, differences can be identified by the presence or absence of errata entries as listed in don knuth's official errata lists.  in tex live, these are combined into one pdf file, accessible with `texdoc errata`.  the [individual errata source files](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archiv/systems/knuth/dist/errata) are available on ctan, but no pdf.

Comment: I just ordered a copy at [Pearson's online store](http://www.informit.com). Unfortunately, the site does not allow you to leave a comment (e.g. for a special request) upon ordering something. I sent an email to their customer service to request the 19th printing. I'll let you know how that pans out.

Comment: The following is on the way: ISBN: 9780201134483,
Title: The TeXbook, 1/e by Donald E. Knuth,
Format: paperback, now in the 33rd printing.

Comment: @Jubobs -- sorry, that won't be the updated version.  *only the hardcover has the updated text.*

Comment: I'm sorry this is turning into a discussion. I may delete my comments and convert our exchange in a full-blown "answer" when I finally find a way to get the right book. Can you confirm that [this](http://www.informit.com/store/computers-typesetting-volume-a-the-texbook-9780201134476) is the book I should order?

Comment: @Jubobs -- yes, c&t volume a (the texbook) is the correct one.  it's really too bad it's still considered the "first edition", with no mention of corrections or updates.  now, keep your fingers crossed, and good luck.

Comment: The two versions are on their way to me, now :s Oh well... The good thing is that I'll be able to thoroughly compare them :) Thanks for your help.