# original Tex book

Tags: plain-tex, books, knuth

Is there original TexBook by Knuth? Everything I've found surfing the Internet does not seem complete book, I want to learn pure plain-Tex, try it,compare its advantages and disadvantages with LaTex and so on. Sorry if it is a duplicate.

Comment: Go into a library (if you're a student, go into the library of your college). Most (science oriented) should have it.

Comment: @Skillmon, I am from Russia, there's cult of M$ word everywhere, and tex and co is not widely used

Comment: I'm from Germany and here most of the people use MS Wort, too. But still, the library of my University has multiple copies of the TeXBook around. So if there is a University around you that teaches physics, maths or something like that, chances are that it has the TeXBook.

Comment: TeX by Topic is available for free, and might be installed with your LaTeX distribution, try `texdoc texbytopic` from a command line/terminal. (Or get it from CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/texbytopic) The TeXbook is not available for free, though the source is also available on CTAN.

Comment: Perhaps of interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7278/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62903/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290306/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49/ Edit: And https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/should-i-read-donald-knuths-the-texbook/10844#10844

Comment: The source of the TeX Book is available for free, so you can read its code. Otherwise, you have to beg, borrow or buy a copy. (It is quite expensive, sadly.)

Comment: A note: Any links to PDF versions of _The TeXbook_ should be flagged and will be deleted. The copyright status of the work is clear: it's _not_ legitimately available as a PDF.

Comment: welcome to plain TeX users:)

Comment: This is also a topic that I am very much interested, however, your question has conflicting statements. If you are asking whether there is an original TexBook by Knuth, yes there is; but you already know this. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @berkus the op seems to mean "where can I find an online copy (pdf?) to download it". The short answer, as others have pointed out, is "nowhere", at least legally; what you can get readily is the source code, under the explicit condition of not texing it into the printable book.

Comment: You can learn "pure plain TeX" from many sources; my absolute favourite (also strongly recommended by Hans Hagen in the preface to the [ConTeXt manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf)) is _A Beginner's Book of TeX_ by Raymond Seroul and Silvio Levy. Look for the book if you can find it (it will take you from beginner to expert); otherwise, free online resources include [*A Gentle Introduction to TeX*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/gentle/gentle.pdf) by Michael Doob (`texdoc gentle`) and [*TeX for the impatient*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/impatient/book.pdf) by Abrahams+Hargreaves+Berry.

Comment: @erreka, no, I more about "where can I find book with lots of examples", cause there's no such a problem with LaTex

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, thanks for the point, A Beginner's Book of TeX  looks and seems really useful with overall explanation